# Do mortals also reduce superficial damage in Vampire V5?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I'm a storyteller from Vampire v20, and there, vampires reduce bashing damage (that is, the equivalent for superficial damage in v5) because they are undead. But if I understand v5 rules right, superficial damage is halved almost every time, even if you are not. Is that true? Or do only undead halve their damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, superficial damage is halved in V5 for mortals and vampires alike. (p.126) This replaces what used to be handled by the soak roll.